# In which cases is this algorithm ineffective?

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm

It's about parallel matrix vector multiplication with multiple threads. The lines of the matrix will be "split" into blocks of as similar size as possible so each thread as about the same amount of lines to multiply, so the program is as fast as possible.

So I have a matrix a, number of threads t, block of lines for each thread s, the individual threads i and start of the block and end of the block which the thread should go through.

I have this algorithm:

```
01: int s = (int) Math.ceil((double) a.length / t);
02: for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
03:   start = i * s;
04:   end = Math.min((i + 1) * s, a.length);
05:   // ... create worker and threads
06: }
```

a.length is the number of lines of which the matrix consists.

Now my question is in which cases this algorithm proves to be ineffective... because apart from the obvious one (no threads obviously produces an error because of dividing by 0), I only have that there is one thread with 1 line and the other 7 threads with 8 lines if I have 57 lines and 8 threads... but it wouldnt be more effective if i had 7 threads with 7 lines and one thread with 8 lines would it?

Comment: The second scenario intuitively sounds more reasonable too me. Well, the algorithm will be especially ineffective if there is too few data for each thread to process. Then the creation of those threads will cost you more than you gain from the parallelism.

Comment: Another case where it can be ineffective is if different threads are accessing data that is close to each other.  The problem happens when a page is shared between CPUs, and the two CPUs have to lock things up to coordinate access.  Then you essentially go single threaded but with a bunch of locking overhead.